# gearman is missing from your system

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

### Description

Trying to install the [laelaps/symfony-gearman-bundle](https://github.com/laelaps/symfony-gearman-bundle) via `composer require laelaps/symfony-gearman-bundle` with a few errors, and I'm having a hard time understanding what they mean.

### Error

> Problem 1
>
> ```
> - laelaps/symfony-gearman-bundle 1.1.x-dev requires ext-gearman * -> the requested PHP extension gearman is missing from your system.
> - laelaps/symfony-gearman-bundle 1.x-dev requires ext-gearman * -> the requested PHP extension gearman is missing from your system.
> - laelaps/symfony-gearman-bundle 1.0.0 requires ext-gearman * -> the requested PHP extension gearman is missing from your system.
> - Installation request for laelaps/symfony-gearman-bundle 1.*@dev -> satisfiable by laelaps/symfony-gearman-bundle[1.0.0, 1.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev].
> ```

I've already insalled gearman via [`apt-get install gearman-job-server`](http://gearman.org/getting-started/)
I've searched around for a solution without much success.

### Question

How do I correctly install the missing php ext gearman?

Comment: Have you checked the extension is added correctly to `php.ini` and have you restarted Apache? `phpinfo() will show if the extension has installed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've already installed gearman via `apt-get install gearman-job-server`
>   I've searched around for a solution without much success.

This is your issue. You haven't installed the *php* extension - you've just installed the program.

If you use the command `apt-cache search gearman` you can see all packages in aptitude relating to the keyword "gearman":

```
aj@dev ~ $ apt-cache search gearman
drizzle-plugin-gearman-udf - Gearman User Defined Functions for Drizzle
drizzle-plugin-logging-gearman - Gearman Logging for Drizzle
gearman - Distributed job queue
gearman-job-server - Job server for the Gearman distributed job queue
gearman-server - Gearman distributed job server and Perl interface
gearman-tools - Tools for the Gearman distributed job queue
libgearman-client-async-perl - asynchronous client for the Gearman distributed j                                                                                                                                      ob system
libgearman-client-perl - client for the Gearman distributed job system
libgearman-dbg - transitional dummy package
libgearman-dev - Development files for the Gearman Library
libgearman-doc - API Documentation for the Gearman Library
libgearman7 - Library providing Gearman client and worker functions
libgearman7-dbg - Debug symbols for the Gearman Client Library
mod-gearman-doc - Documentation and examples for Mod-Gearman
mod-gearman-module - Nagios/Icinga event broker module for Mod-Gearman
mod-gearman-tools - Tools for mod-gearman
mod-gearman-worker - Worker agent for Mod-Gearman
pandora-build - autotools made better, faster stronger

php5-gearman - PHP wrapper to libgearman
^^^^^^^^^^^^

pnp4nagios-bin - Nagios addon to create graphs from performance data (binaries)
python-gear - Pure Python Async Gear Protocol Library
python-gearman - Python interface to the Gearman system
python-gearman.libgearman - Python wrapper of libgearman
python3-gearman.libgearman - Python 3 wrapper of libgearman
```

If you look you can see that there's a PHP *extension* named `php5-gearman`. That's what this is what your error is referring to:

> the requested **PHP extension gearman** is missing from your system.

So simply install `php5-gearman` and restart php/your webserver:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gearman
sudo service php5-fpm restart # restart if you use php5-fpm
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the PHP dependencies as follow:

```
sudo apt-get install libgearman-dev
```

Check [this article](http://masnun.com/2011/09/30/installing-and-getting-started-with-gearman.html) for further detail based on your SO.

Probably you need to add the library on the php conf system as example:

```
echo 'extension = gearman.so' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/gearman.ini
```

Hope this help

Comment: Already tried that prior to asking the question, this did not work.

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial, solution that worked for me was following these steps:

## Install additional packages for compiling

`apt-get -y install wget unzip re2c libgearman-dev`

## Install from source

`mkdir -p /tmp/install`

`cd /tmp/install`

`wget https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman/archive/master.zip`

`unzip master.zip`

`cd pecl-gearman-master`

`phpize`

`./configure`

`make install`

`echo "extension=gearman.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gearman.ini`

`phpenmod -v ALL -s ALL gearman`

## Verify if module is really installed

`php -m | grep gearman`

## Delete installation files

`rm -rf /tmp/install/pecl-gearman-master`

`rm /tmp/install/master.zip`